How to enable SQLite3 cli to load an extension
I have downloaded the extension I want in sqlite3 which is spellfix and when I open sqlite3 to enable it the cli is not able to recognize the sqlite function
Not sure how to load the extension spellfix.dll
pretty much I have the same error descriped here (I checked the answers too and not working)
I have tried the following
discordbot\database> sqlite3 database.db
SQLite version 3.42.0 2023-05-16 12:36:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .load ./spellfix
Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "load". Enter ".help" for help
sqlite> .dbconfig load_extension on
     load_extension on
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('./spellfix');
Parse error: no such function: load_extension
  SELECT load_extension('./spellfix');
         ^--- error here
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('spellfix');
Parse error: no such function: load_extension
  SELECT load_extension('spellfix');
         ^--- error here
sqlite>


First check your current directory in the sqlite shell (assuming that your are on Windows here given the .dll file).
sqlite> .shell cd

The output of this command will tell you where on your filesystem to place the extension. For example, you might be working in a specific project directory. Then, place your .dll file in that location. Then, within the sqlite shell you can load your extension.
sqlite> .load spellfix.dll

On my machine (a Linux machine), I see output like this.
~ $ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.46.0 2024-05-23 13:25:27
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .shell pwd
/home/admin
sqlite> .load myextension.so
Error: myextension.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
sqlite> 

If you don't see similar output, try grabbing the sqlite-tools-win-x64-*.zip file from the SQLite Downloads page sqlite.org/download.html and using the sqlite3.exe found in there.

my .dll file is in my working directory.. when I run this command I get Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "load". Enter ".help" for help

What version of the sqlite client are you using? You should see this when you start it up. For example SQLite version 3.46.0 The client needs to call sqlite3_enable_load_extension, which the standard sqlite3 client does by default. Maybe try using the standard client rather than one in an IDE or similar?

I am using SQLite version 3.42.0

I think that the version of the sqlite3 client that you are using has either compiled out the call to enable loading extensions or otherwise disabled the .load function. Are you in an embedded environment? (on an Android phone maybe?)

Try grabbing the sqlite-tools-win-x64-*.zip file from the SQLite Downloads page https://www.sqlite.org/download.html and using the sqlite3.exe found in there.

Thanks this fixed the issue and .load now appears and extension is loaded!
